# When entering the page for the second time, can't receive the data from graphql

Tags: flutter, graphql

I was trying to get data from our end point through graphql, things works just fine when I enter the page first time, page render "Loading" and print out the data after receive the data from query.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt4H0.png)

But if I click on previous page button, and then go back to "SiteMap" page again, the error occurred.
The error is:

```
Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'iterator' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: iterator)
```

My code:

```
Query(
  options: QueryOptions(
    document: getSitemapsGSCQuery(),
  ),
  builder: (QueryResult result,{VoidCallback refetch, FetchMore fetchMore}) {
    if (result.errors != null) {
      return Text(result.errors.toString());
    }
    if (result.loading) {
      return Text('Loading');
    }
    print(result.data["sitemaps"]["sitemaps"]); // get null when entering second time
    List _sitemaps = result.data["sitemaps"]["sitemaps"]; 
    for (var sitemap in _sitemaps) { // get error here for "_sitemaps"
      // do sth
    }
  },
)
```

As a newbie flutter programmer, I have no idea what reason might cause this...

Comment: _"But if I click on previous page button, and then go back to "SiteMap" page again... _" How you call PageB from SiteMap?

Comment: Is there something in initState regarding this? (it will not be run upon returning)

Comment: I build a drawer and while tapping it, I call `Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/sitemap');`

Comment: Actually I didn't set initState for this page yet.